# List all files with the same inode number?

Tags: ls, inode

Let's say when I do `ls -li` inside a directory, I get this:

```
12353538 -rw-r--r-- 6 me me 1650 2013-01-10 16:33 fun.txt
```

As the output shows, the file *fun.txt* has ***6*** hard links; and the inode number is *12353538*.

How do I find all the hard links for the file i.e. files with the same inode number?

Comment: See also the answers to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35292/quickly-find-which-files-belongs-to-a-specific-inode-number) question.

Comment: Are you looking for all directory entries, or an inode? (there is at most one file per file-system with each i-node number).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The basic premise is to use:

```
find /mount/point -mount -samefile /mount/point/your/file
```

On systems with `findmnt` you can derive the mount point like this:

```
file=/path/to/your/file
find "$(findmnt -o TARGET -cenT "$file")" -mount -samefile "$file"
```

It's important not to search from `/` - unless the target file is on that filesystem - because inode numbers are reused in each mounted filesystem.

Comment: @TheoneManis I just noticed that the other parts of the find call are not necessary. `find` is clever enough to use them implicitely. Usually you have to give `find` a search path and have to tell it that is shall not leave these file systems (via symlinks or mount points). But when looking for hard links it's clear on which file system to search.

Comment: Hauke, that depends on the version of find you're using. The GNU version might do that, but the BSD one does not, and this will not work as-is on Mac.

Comment: You may want to add `-xdev` to avoid descending into directories in other filesystems, otherwise you might find another file with the same inode number located in another filesystem.

Comment: The near-equivalent to `-samefile` on HP-UX is `-linkedto` (though it is slightly different: a search path must still be specified, for example).

Comment: Note that if you are not in the root of your mount point, find will explore only subfolders of the current folder. So you should really say something like `find /mount/point -samefile /mount/point/your/file`

Comment: @Calimo You may edit the answer.

Answer (score 61):

If you already have the inode number you can use find's `-inum` option:

```
find /mount/point -xdev -inum 12353538
```

(some `find` implementations also support `-mount` as an equivalent of `-xdev` though only `-xdev` is standard).

Answer (score 2):

[`ffind`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-ffind/) from [The Sleuth Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sleuth_Kit) can find all the file names for an inode, including deleted file names.

For example:

```
sudo ffind -a /dev/sda3 $(stat --format=%i ~/just_a_test)
```

yields

```
* /home/me/empty_1
* /home/me/hard_link_to_empty1
/home/me/just_a_test
/home/me/hard_link_to_just_a_test
```

The entries with a preceding star are previous file names that don't exist anymore (because the file was renamed or deleted).

---

I use `$(stat --format=%i ~/just_a_test)` to get the inode of the file.

To get the partition of the file name programmatically (`/dev/sda3` in the previous example), you can use [`df`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html):

```
file=~/just_a_test; sudo ffind -a $(df -P "$file" | awk 'END{print $1}') $(stat --format=%i "$file")
```

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to the previous answers.

Note that the `stat` binary can not only provide one with the inode, but its corresponding device's mount point too. The snippet below uses this to solve the 'usual' use case:

```
fn_hardlinks() {
  declare target; target="$1" && shift
  [ ! -e "$target" ] && \
    { echo "[error] invalid target: '$target'" 1>&2; exit 1; }
  stat '/' 2>/dev/null 1>&2 || \
    { echo "[error] no functioning 'stat' binary found'" 1>&2; exit 1; }
  declare mount; mount="$(stat -c '%m' "$target")"
  declare inode; inode="$(stat -c '%i' "$target")"
  [ "x${mount[-1]}" != "x/" ] && mount+="/"
  find "$mount" -xdev -inum "$inode" 2>/dev/null
}

alias hardlinks=fn_hardlinks
```

and running:

```
> hardlinks ./resources/sphinx/gitinfo.py
/home/user/build/z-documentation/resources/sphinx/gitinfo.py
/home/user/build/sphinx-gitinfo/git/sphinx-gitinfo/gitinfo.py
```

PS: watch out for `exit` vs `return` depending on how you use this!

Comment: Why `fn_hardlinks` with an alias rather than a function named `hardlinks`?

Comment: no reason here - it's a no-op as you rightly allude to. but given the context that this was ripped from a larger pool of utils - because to those unseasoned in shell, function calls don't stand out (hence the prefix), and the alias is for consistency and anticipation of parameterisation